# Skip validation on certain field when a condition is met

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

Hi Im having troubble trying to do the following.

Im making a checkout page, I have a form like this

```
  <%= form_for([@ofert, @order], builder: FoundationFormBuilder) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :invoice_address do |builder| %>
        <%= render partial: 'invoice_address_fields', locals: { f: builder } %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.check_box :invoice_equals_shipping, checked: true, label: 'My Invoice address is the same Shipping address' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :shipping_address do |builder| %>
      <%= render partial: 'shipping_address_fields', locals: { f: builder } %>
    <% end %>

    .....
    <% end %>
```

well the checkbox "My Invoice address is the same Shipping address" is checked by de fault, the "shipping_address" field is hidden by default using jquery.

Well both fields are empty at the beginning, So the user usually will fill the invoice_address field and will leave the checkbox "My Invoice address is the same Shipping address" checked, well the problem is that the hidden field "shipping_address" is validated "field cannot be blank"

How can I validate that when checkbox is checked do not validate the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition to `validates` in your model. Something like:

```
validates :shipping_address, presence: true, unless: :invoice_equals_shipping?
```

Comment: You rock! thank you very much I just added your line in my Order model, since :shipping_address was a nested attribute. For those who want to make more customized validations reffer to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation. Thanks again!